# Radical Inequality related to three variables

Tags: inequality

Prove the following.

$$\sum_\text{cyclic}\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{(a^{2}+b^{2})(a^{2}-ab+b^{2})}{2}}\leq\dfrac{2}{3}\left(\sum_\text{cyclic}\dfrac{1}{a+b}\right)\left(\sum_\text{cyclic}a^{2}\right)$$

Comment: Why do you use "displaystyle" in a case like this instead of just using an actual display?  (I changed it to the latter.)

Comment: Context would be helpful - where did this inequality come from? What did you try to prove it?

Comment: And the most important question - what are the conditions on $a,b$? In fact, is there only two variables here, or is there more?